# how to identify an object property with iMacros

Tags: excel, vba, imacros

I writing an macro with vba (excel) and iMacros.  When I record clicking in a field, this is the info I get:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-1317

the issue I'm having is the number at the end of that string changes each time.  I can click in it with :

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-*

but I need the number because the next 3 fields are based on that number.  For instance, if it is 1317, the next number is 1326.  If it is 1350, then the next number is 1359.

Is there a way to capture that number?  Thanks for the help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum..., you should always mention your Environment/FCI (Full Config Info) when asking a Qt, not all (iMacros) Commands are implemented for all Browsers/Versions, but OK, this one will work for all Browsers:

=> Yep, easy with 'EXTRACT=HTM' on your Field + 'EVAL()' & 'match()' or I prefer 'split()' (x2) which I find easier to use than 'match()'.

That will give stg like:

```
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-* EXTRACT=HTM
SET gwt-uid_Nb EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var y,z; y=s.split('gwt-uid-'); z=y[1].split(' '); z[0];")
PROMPT _{{gwt-uid_Nb}}_
```

=> Replace the 'Space' in the 2nd 'split()' with whatever unique Char/String comes after the 4 Digits in the 'EXTRACT=HTM'... (But avoid Double Quotes and Backslashes...!)

(Not tested as you didn't provide the URL of the Page...)

And you probably don't even need that ID-Number by using "Relative Positioning" for your next 3 Fields...

Comment: @chivracq...........Thanks for the info.  I didn't provide the URL since it was a system our company developed.  I'm going to try this today.  Can you give me a little more info on Relative Positioning?  I haven't used that before?  I'm also having trouble with a checkbox (can't check it).  I can record it and when I put it in my VBA (TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT: CHECKBOX ATTR=*&&CHECKED:True &&TYPE:checkbox && VALUE:on CONTENT=YES") and run it, nothing happens, box not checked, no error message, nothing. Any suggestions for this issue?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Oh...!, good, I was a bit surprised not to notice any Follow-up on this Thread...

- But, hum, could you mention your FCI like I asked you...?

- "Relative Positioning": Well, you have several Sections in the Wiki about it, read them first and "experiment" with it, then OK, I'll be happy to give more Details if you don't understand stg...

- About your 'CHECKBOX' Statement:

Comment: Pfff, Formatting of my Comment is lost and I cannot edit it anymore... (And Field is way too short...) I can't manage to format my Comment a bit correctly...

- About your 'CHECKBOX' Statement:
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT: CHECKBOX ATTR=*&&CHECKED:True &&TYPE:checkbox && VALUE:on CONTENT=YES"
I don't know, I would need to be able to have a look at the Page, but your Statement contains extra Spaces and some orphan Double Quote at its end and you've removed some Attribute(s) from what iMacros recorded, so your CB has now maybe become 'POS=2' or 'POS=3' etc...

Comment: Instead of recording the Click in the CB (which iMacros will record with 2 Statements),  you can try clicking "only" on the Label (which should select the CB as well) and Labels are usually easier to identify than CB's.

Comment: @chivracq....Imacros 10.3, IE browser, Windows 7 Enterprise.  I think that checkbox code may have been recorded with the Expert mode.  When I added the code above for the number property, I'm getting a -1100 error wrong format message.  Thanks again.

Comment: @chivracq..............I started using the label and that is working like a charm.  Thanks for the suggestion......

Comment: "My" 'EVAL()' Statement I think is correct for the Number except for the 'Space' used for the 2nd 'split()' like I mentioned.
Does the 'TAG POS=1 + EXTRACT=HTM' return the Data you expect, containing this "gwt-uid-1317" you expect...?

Comment: @chivracq............I haven't been able to get the EVAL statement to work.  I was getting a "end of statement" error message.  I ended up clicking on the label for the first field and then using relative positioning........Still need to do more testing but it looks promising....thanks

Comment: Well, I don't know, it should work, unless I made a Typo as I couldn't test it on the Page, but I've checked it several times so it should be OK...
Your Site is Internal, OK, but can't you upload some HTML Saveas of the Page to the Thread (don't know if that's possible on this Forum)?, then it would take me a few min to get your Script to work...
Pfff, thought it was an "easy" Case, never expected it to become so lengthy, but that's most often the case when we (Advanced Users) don't have direct Access to the Site/Page...

Comment: But, pff, I've asked you to mention your FCI, I still don't see that Info in your OP, maybe you mentioned it in some Comment but each time I come back to this Thread I waste some time to look for it...
=> Can you add it clearly to your OP...?
(Sorry but I "handle" 10-20 Threads everyday, I don't remember everything for all of them, and this one was already from 2 weeks ago, oops...!, I need to find that Info quick without searching in numerous Comments, and the Layout on this Forum is not very easy to search any Info...!)

Comment: Hum, and sorry to "push" you, but I just got some Mail-Notification from the Forum (x4 actually) to which I just responded, while I see that your last Reply was already from 10 days ago... (I don't understand everything, ah-ah...!)

Comment: Hum, I think that was the end of my Contribution to this Forum and trying to help Users, ah-ah...!
Thanks to the "-1" for my Answer, I cannot post anymore on the Forum, that's a bit bit useless, ah-ah...! Nouja, never mind...

Comment: @chivracq..........I never could get it to work but ended up switching to Relative Positioning and that solved my issue.  Thanks for all of the feedback and help  you have provided.

Comment: OK, good to hear... (I won't be able to help you anymore for any other Threads as I cannot post on this Forum anymore because of the useless Rep-Point System, but you can always post on the iMacros Forum if your Pb cannot be solved on this Forum and if you need my Help... (I'm Mod there...))

Comment: But hum, using Relative Positioning was as well the easiest Solution that I had mentioned in my Answer, so I still don't understand why my Answer ended up with "-1" while it is a correct Answer in which I gave several Solutions... (And this "-1" makes that I am not allowed to post on the Forum anymore, very clever System, ah-ah...!)

Comment: @chivracq..........If I made it a -1, it was an accident as I surely didn't intend that.  I have tried to rectify it by accepting the answer. and removing the -1.  The answer you provided on relative positioning was the solution I used.  I appreciate the help you have provided on the topic.

Comment: @Shaves, don't worry it wasn't you, but your +1 might help, some fake User on the iMacros Forum who didn't want to mention his Environment got a bit angry at me and downvoted all my Answers on SOF, which managed to "kill" me thanks to the Rep-System on this Forum...
Thanks for all the +1...!